# How to retrieve the current state of AWS amplify datastore?

Tags: aws-amplify

When using AWS amplify datastore it's difficult to know which behavior will datastore have. Is the datastore synced or is the sync outstanding. The Datastore API has no API method to get the current state.

Answer (score 3):

With datastore version 2.2.2 you can listen to the event hub.

The channel is `datastore`

**Register to channel**

```
import { Hub } from '@aws-amplify/core';

Hub.listen ("datastore", (data) => {
        console.log ('A new event has happened:', data);
})
```

**Example output**

```
await DataStore.clear();
await DataStore.start();
```

generates the following output:

```
A new event has happened:  {"channel":"datastore","payload":{"event":"storageSubscribed"},"source":"","patternInfo":[]}

A new event has happened:  {"channel":"datastore","payload":{"event":"networkStatus","data":{"active":true}},"source":"","patternInfo":[]}

A new event has happened:  {"channel":"datastore","payload":{"event":"outboxStatus","data":{"isEmpty":true}},"source":"","patternInfo":[]}

A new event has happened:  {"channel":"datastore","payload":{"event":"subscriptionsEstablished"},"source":"","patternInfo":[]}

A new event has happened:  {"channel":"datastore","payload":{"event":"syncQueriesStarted","data":{"models":["ModelX","ModelY","ModelLala"]}},"source":"","patternInfo":[]}

A new event has happened:  {"channel":"datastore","payload":{"event":"modelSynced","data":{"isFullSync":true,"isDeltaSync":false,"counts":{"new":5,"updated":0,"deleted":2}}},"source":"","patternInfo":[]}

A new event has happened:  {"channel":"datastore","payload":{"event":"modelSynced","data":{"isFullSync":true,"isDeltaSync":false,"counts":{"new":296,"updated":0,"deleted":2}}},"source":"","patternInfo":[]}

A new event has happened:  {"channel":"datastore","payload":{"event":"modelSynced","data":{"isFullSync":true,"isDeltaSync":false,"counts":{"new":8155,"updated":0,"deleted":0}}},"source":"","patternInfo":[]}

A new event has happened:  {"channel":"datastore","payload":{"event":"syncQueriesReady"},"source":"","patternInfo":[]}

A new event has happened:  {"channel":"datastore","payload":{"event":"ready"},"source":"","patternInfo":[]}
```

**See also:**

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/pull/5942

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4808

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/hub/q/platform/js#channels